# What's the best way to aggregate date time by hourly interval?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble parsing my date time column that are currently in 'chr' type. I want the date time to be grouped by hour interval and sum corresponding values, then merge two date frames.

```
a <- c("2016-04-12 12:00:00", "2016-04-12 12:01:00")
   b <- c(10, 20)
   df_1 <- data.frame(a,b)
   names(df_1) <- c('Date', 'Steps') 

c1 <- c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/12/2016 05:00:00 PM")
   d <- c(20,8)
   df_2 <- data.frame(c1,d) 
   names(df_2) <- c('Date', 'Intensity')
```

`df_1` (with minutes interval) to join `df_2` (with hourly interval but the whole day is separated by AM PM)

I have tried converting it using `as.POSIXct` and ymd to datetime type but it's returning `NA` values. I tried below code from a post I saw before, it worked but it didn't record the PM time of the day. code below

```
df_1 <- aggregate(df_1["Steps"], 
                 list(Date=cut(as.POSIXct(df_1$Date), "hour")),
                 sum)
```

Also, I wanna remove that AM PM on the second date frame.

Comment: I am confused about what your final output would look like given your sample data. Could you please provide an example of the final desired dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `aggregate` for `df_1` appears to work fine, for `df_2` you need to define the time format, using `strptime` which converts character objects to `"POSIX*t"`.

```
aggregate(df_2["Intensity"], 
          list(Date=cut(strptime(df_2$Date, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'), "hour")),
          sum)
#                  Date Intensity
# 1 2016-04-12 05:00:00         8
# 2 2016-04-12 12:00:00        20
```

*Explanation:*

- `%m/%d/%Y` month, day, year, separated by a slash
- the space between date and time
- `%I:%M:%S` hour (12h format), minute, second, separated by a colon
- another space
- `%p` the AM/PM indicator

Read `?strptime` for different options, since this may also depend on your locale.

Comment: yes, it worked with df_1 but it stopped at 12:00:00, same with df_2, then it goes on the next day. I need the whole 24H interval. will the mutate, groupby, summarise work in this?

Comment: @Bojji I'm not absolutely sure what you mean, I see no date changes. The 12:01 of df_1 is assigned to interval starting at 12:00.

Comment: @Bojji I found a mistake, we may not use the abbreviation when there's AM/PM, please check edited answer.

Comment: I'll rewrite the example and edit the post soon but basically I just want the sum of data per hour of the day, like for the date 4-12-2016 Im expecting 24 rows since there are 24 hours in a day, in the code we were working on it only returned 12rows that from 1:00:00 to 12:00:00

Comment: @Bojji Actually you should be able to merge both aggregates using `merge(agg1, agg2, all=TRUE)`. Yeah edit it, I'm following you.

Comment: I couldn't make a reproducible code, the code is working it's just that it's not the result I wanted. everything is fine except that the code is deleting the PM part of the day it's only returning the AM part. thank you